# Is there a better way to get a value from a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, block, option-type

I have been using `if yield self[x]` to evaluate whether a block returns true or false.
I need to make the block optional, and I see suggestions to do `yield if block_given?`.
How can I combine these two lines?

Comment: Why not show us what you're trying to do, rather than describe it? That way we can fix your code rather than you try to shoehorn something in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
if block_given? && yield(self[x])
  # ...
end
```

This condition will always fail when no block is given, i.e. whatever is in place of `# ...` won't be evaluated. If you want the condition to succeed if no block is given, do this instead:

```
if !block_given? || yield(self[x])
  # ...
end
```

Or this, although I think it's harder to read:

```
unless block_given? && !yield(self[x])
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if block_given?
   if yield self[x]
      # Do something....
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append a condition to the entire `if` block:

```
if yield self[x]
  # do something...
end if block_given?
```